# When I print a string value to console it prints but when i try to put this string in double String array it returns empty

Tags: java, arrays, string, doc

I am trying to read a doc file with java and try to extract table value from the file. I can read the file and I can print the table values one by one, but when I try to assign those table values to a 2D String array, it puts empty String for some values from the table.

This is the code.

```
Table table=range.getTable(tablePar);
TableRow row1=table.getRow(0);
int a = table.numRows();
int b = row1.numCells();
String  atable[][] = new String[a][b];

for(int rowIdx=0;rowIdx<table.numRows();rowIdx++)
{
    TableRow row=table.getRow(rowIdx);
    System.out.println("row "+(rowIdx+1)+",is table header: "+row.isTableHeader());
    for(int colIdx=0;colIdx<row.numCells();colIdx++)
    {
        TableCell cell=row.getCell(colIdx);
        System.out.println("column "+(colIdx+1)+",text= "+cell.getParagraph(0).text());
        String toWrite = cell.getParagraph(0).text();
        System.out.println("toWrite: " + toWrite);                    
        atable[rowIdx][colIdx] = toWrite;
        System.out.println("atable: " + atable[rowIdx][colIdx] + "  "+ rowIdx+  "x" + colIdx);

    }
}
System.out.println("******************************************************************");
for(int i = 0; i<a; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<b; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(atable[i][j]+ "    ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

And this is the sample output:

```
row 1,is table header: false
column 1,text= Institution
toWrite: Institution
atable: Institution  0x0
column 2,text= Middle East Technical University
toWrite: Middle East Technical University
atable: Middle East Technical University  0x1
row 2,is table header: false
column 1,text=  Date:   from (month / year):
toWrite:    Date:   from (month / year):
  1x0
```

As it can be seen, it prints the cell value correct, it prints the String value that is obtained from cell, but it does not assign that string to String array.
The problem occurs only for the String "Date:   from (month / year):"

Also when i try this atable[rowIdx][colIdx] = "Date:    from (month / year):"; 
it works perfectly.

Comment: I don't see how that output can be correct. There should be `atable:   Date:   from (month / year):`. Have you tried running the code with breakpoints and stepping through each line?

Comment: You may find the [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) project helpful for an alternative approach.

Comment: Yes I tried but it just does not add this string to array. It prints the string, i tried to write it to excel and that worked as well. Also when i try this atable[rowIdx][colIdx] = "Date: from (month / year):"; it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Java has only [one-dimensional arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#One-dimensional_arrays). So if you want a [two-dimensional array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#Multidimensional_arrays), you need to make an array of arrays, *and for each row declare a new array*.

So, roughly like this:

```
String[][] cells = new String[table.numRows()][]);
for (int x=0; x<table.numRows(); x++) {
    cells[x] = new String[table.numCols()];
    for(int y=0; y<table.numCols(); y++) {
        // code goes here
    }
}
```

Arrays in Java are a bit of a pain, and best avoided if you can.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in my code it adds every other string in the table from doc into the array but it does not add the string  "Date: from (month / year):" If this problem is really oriented from the way i created the 2d array, then why it works perfectly for other strings.

Comment: Have you tried it this way? I don't know why your code works in a certain way; that's for you to find out using a debugger. What I do know is that the way you declare an array simply doesn't work in Java. If you don't believe that, then I cannot help you.